# Linear systems of inequations with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a linear systems of inequations in Python.
My linear system look something like this :

- 3 * x1 + 2 * x2 + 4 * x3 > 0
- x1 - 4 * x2 - 7 * x3 > 0

I've tried to use **NumPy** but linalg.solve(a, b) is designed for equations (=) and I have inequations (>).
I've thought about adding variables to my problem to trasnform inequations into equation like :

- 3 * x1 + 2 * x2 + 4 * x3 - x4 + 0 * x5 = 0
- x1 + 4 * x2 + 7 * x3 + 0 * x4 - x5 = 0

x4 and x5 being > 0.

But I don't know how many constraints I'm going to have and I don't know if linalg.solve gives only strictly positive value to variables.

---

I've also look into **SciPy** linprog.

I could add an objective function like x1 + x2 + x3, that would'nt be a problem. 
But with linprog I have only inequations as <**=** 0, but I want to exclude the value 0. It would be okay if I could have < 0.

I hope my problem is clear.
I've asked Google for some help, but find nothing. I guess I'm missing something since I can't be the only one with this problem.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What would a "solution" to a set of in equations look like?

Comment: It seems to me like these 2 equations would be satisfied for all positive x1, x2, and x3.

Comment: A solution would be value for x1; x2;x3. If there are multiple solutions, I just want one of them,  any one.  I edited my message so that not all positive x1,x2,x3 would be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to introduce a tolerance that defines how close you can come to zero and perhaps iterate on the tolerance value

I.e.  Rewrite

```
3 * x1 + 2 * x2 + 4 * x3 > 0
x1 + 4 * x2 + 7 * x3 > 0
```

as

```
3 * x1 + 2 * x2 + 4 * x3 >= t
x1 + 4 * x2 + 7 * x3 >= t
```

Now, you can use spicy.linprog to solve this.
where `t > 0`. 
Perhaps `t >= 0.01` is acceptable as a starting point.
Then iterate on  `t in [0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, ... ]`

At some point, your solution might start changing by less than your precision requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What kind of solutions you are targeting? What should that iteration achieve? Instead of iterating some t-candidates, you can directly optimize these (given only one extreme).

Comment: Thank you Anish,  I'm going to try that. What do you mean Sascha by directly optimize them?

Comment: Sascha, did you mean to treat t as the optimization objective. I was thinking that the linear equation is a set of constraints with a seperate objective. If that is not the case, I agree, one could just optimize for t.